# Prove that $C′$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group. Let $C′=\{ a\in G:(ax)^2=(xa)^2 \forall x \in G\}$. 
Prove that $C′$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I already proved that this is closed under multiplication, but I don't know how to prove it for inverses.

Answer (score 3):

If $a \in C'$, then $axax=xaxa$ for all $x \in G$, so that
$$
a^{-1} xa^{-1}x = (x^{-1}ax^{-1}a)^{-1} = (ax^{-1}ax^{-1})^{-1} = xa^{-1}xa^{-1},
$$
that is, $a^{-1} \in C'$.

Added later: Perhaps this is easier to understand. Start with $ax^{-1}ax^{-1} = x^{-1}ax^{-1}a$. Then taking the inverse of both sides gives $xa^{-1}xa^{-1} = a^{-1}xa^{-1}x$.

Comment: how do we know that a(x^−1)a(x^−1)=(x^−1)a(x^−1)a?

Comment: Because $a \in C'$ and $x^{-1} \in G$.

Comment: got it now, sorry.  
and thank you